# Is any function from set X with uncountable discrete topology continuous?

Tags: general-topology, continuity

As we know that every function from discrete topological space to any topological space is continuous. And also that function from any topological to uncountable discrete topological space need not be continous . But is there any function from some topological space to uncountable discrete topological space exist which is continuous?

Answer (score 1):

The identity function from any topological space into itseld is always continuous. Also, every constant function is continuous.